# Есть ли компонент в Delphi для перетаскивания файлов?

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

Есть ли в Delphi компонент или какая-нибудь функция, чтобы я мог перетащить файл.txt на форму, и все что внутри этого файла скопировалось в таблицу StringGrid?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Компонента не знаю, но именно для файлов, в принципе, всё не так сложно:

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  Dialogs, StdCtrls;

type
  TMemo = class(StdCtrls.TMemo)
  protected
    procedure WM_DROPFILES(var Message: TWMDropFiles); message WM_DROPFILES;
  end;

  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Memo: TMemo;
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

uses
  ShellAPI;

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  DragAcceptFiles(Memo.Handle, True);
end;

{ TMemo }

procedure TMemo.WM_DROPFILES(var Message: TWMDropFiles);
var
  NameSize: Cardinal;
  NewSize: Cardinal;
  FileName: PChar;
  Index: Cardinal;
  Count: Cardinal;
begin
  // чтобы не делать вложенных try/finally
  FileName := nil;
  // Получаем количество перетащенных файлов
  Count := DragQueryFile(Message.Drop, $FFFFFFFF, FileName, 0);
  try
    // выделяем память под имя файла
    NameSize := 256;
    GetMem(FileName, NameSize);
    // ... и список их имён
    for Index := 0 to Count - 1 do begin
      NewSize := DragQueryFile(Message.Drop, Index, nil, 0) + 1; // +1 для #0 в конце имени
      // проверка на то, что нам хватит места
      if NewSize > NameSize then begin
        NameSize := NewSize;
        ReallocMem(FileName, NameSize);
      end;
      // получаем имя файла, обработка ошибок - в качестве самостоятельной работы :)
      DragQueryFile(Message.Drop, Index, FileName, NameSize);
      // делаем с ним всё что нам нужно
      Lines.Add(FileName);
    end;
  finally
    DragFinish(Message.Drop);
    if FileName <> nil then
      FreeMem(FileName);
  end;
end;

end.
```

Как-то так. Пример [взял отсюда](http://www.delphisources.ru/pages/faq/base/wm_dropfiles.html) и немного модифицировал, чтобы файлы принимала не сама форма, а TMemo на ней.

Comment: Я написал Form7.Memo2.Lines.LoadFromFile(FileName) . При наведении курсор меняется.. и все

Comment: Надо весь код видеть, чтобы что-то понять.

Answer (score 0):

В JEDI есть компонент JvDragDrop (невизуальный). Позволяет гибко настроить параметры "кидания" на разные области вашей формы.

http://wiki.delphi-jedi.org/wiki/JVCL_Help:TJvDragDrop

Answer (score 0):

Компоненты:

1. [Drag and Drop Component Suite](http://melander.dk/delphi/dragdrop)
2. [JVCL](https://sourceforge.net/projects/jvcl/) ([JvDragDrop](http://wiki.delphi-jedi.org/wiki/JVCL_Help:TJvDragDrop)).
3. [Raize DropMaster](http://www.raize.com/devtools/DropMaster/Default.asp)

Программно:

1. [Delphi](http://www.webdelphi.ru/2012/01/zametki-pro-dragdrop-v-delphi/)
2. [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb776905(v=vs.85).aspx)